# How to print every line of processing code in Python?

Tags: python

When testing or creating a new function, I often like to print every line of code that is happening so that I can see how every line is processing.

Is there a way that can serve this purpose? I'm looking for something more convenient so I don't have to type print after every line.

For example, instead of writing this function

```
def test_func():
    l = range(10)
    print l
    l = zip(l,range(30,40))
    print l 
    l = dict(l)
    print l
```

I'd like to write this without writing print, yet still get every line printed

```
def test_func():
    l = range(10)
    l = zip(l,range(30,40))
    l = dict(l)
```

Perhaps I can use a Python decorator or something for this?

Comment: Look into e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/debug.html - this question is too broad for SO as it stands.

Comment: Use a debugger , that's what it does

Comment: I ususally first play around with the individual steps in an interactive session before I write them down in a function.

Comment: I think this is a valid question and well described. It also has a good answer and was very useful for me today. It should not have been closed IMHO.

Comment: I also think this is a valid question, how is it too broad? I run into this daily. I think it should be re-opened.

Comment: I ran into this. I tried a lot of things including 'log' macro via macropy. The closest thing I found was to use pycharm. In pycham I can press "ctrl+shift+e" and it executed the line that the cursor is on in the console, this shows what the statement returns in the console. The key combo also moves caret down, so I can press it repeatedly to run multiple lines quickly or select multiple lines. Not perfect, but kinda works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd better use debugger for that purpose. But if you want to print each line you can run program with 'trace`.

```
python -m trace --trace asd.py 

 --- modulename: asd, funcname: <module>
asd.py(1): def test_func():
asd.py(6): test_func();
 --- modulename: asd, funcname: test_func
asd.py(2):     l = range(10)
asd.py(3):     l = zip(l,range(30,40))
asd.py(4):     l = dict(l)
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

Comment: tracer doesn't seem to sow the output, only what is run

Comment: I have a huge problem. My recent python program does well during normal command line execution. But when I try executing via /etc/rc.local and save the log report to /tmp/rc.local.log, gives me segmentation fault. If I do python -m trace --trace myfile.py, I get nothing other than 500,000 lines of code. I don't think interactive pdb will help in startup scripts. What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use pdb, run your code with pdb as below,

```
python -m pdb create_vpc.py
```

Frequent options used in pdb are,

```
(pdb) n - next line
(pdb) l - print few lines before and after
(pdb) range(10) or yoru variable "test" ---> this prints current value of any variable from stack
(pdb) !val = range(10)   ----> assign any variable while running
```

You can also import the pdb at any point of your program so that it would stop there and give you the console

```
def test_func():
l = range(10)
print l
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()      -----> Program stops here and you can check any current variable status or before and after lines etc
l = zip(l,range(30,40))
print l 
l = dict(l)
print l
```

Comment: You can also use ipdb. Мore comfortable